# Is there a way to attach multiple serial port devices to a single raspberry pi?

Tags: hardware, serial, sensor, gps, gsm

I have three separate devices that all need access to a data serial port on the pi. My devices are an accelerometer, a GPS unit, and a GMS cell service chip. I've found tutorials on how to attach these to the pi and manipulate each individually, but my experiment really needs all three attached at once, and it is my understanding that the pi only has one serial data input.

Is there a solution to attach all three devices to my pi? I'm using a raspberry pi 2.

Comment: Can you be a bit clearer about the nature of those devices "serial" interfaces - perhaps can you identify them or point us to some relevant web-pages.  There some means to provide extra "software" serial ports but there are severe limits (only one can be read at a time IIRC) - I feel it might be possible if there is the equivalent to an I2C or SPI bus to serial device (RS232 type) IC if it can buffer (in FIFOs) data transfers automatically and the amount of data to transfer from all three devices along the I2C or SPI buses is within their capabilities.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could:

- utilize a couple of USB to serial adapters like this [one](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0007T27H8).
- you could use a microcontroller that has multiple serial ports  (e.g. arduino mega) to gather the data and transfer it to the Pi, or
- you could get a serial to I2c or spi [adapter](https://www.sparkfun.com/products/9981) that connects to the GPIO pins.

More info can be found in this [thread](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=44&t=62194).